# Formula for given Input-Output Set

Tags: algorithms, logarithms, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Need to design an **Algorithm**, which should gave $\mathtt{[Output]}$ as per the $\mathtt{[Input]}$ mentioned below.

| $\mathcal{Input}$ | $\mathcal{Output}$ |
| --- | --- |
| $0$ | $1$ |
| $1$ | $2$ |
| $2$ | $4$ |
| $3$ | $4$ |
| $4$ | $8$ |
| $5$ | $8$ |
| $6$ | $8$ |
| $7$ | $8$ |
| $8$ | $16$ |
| $9$ | $16$ |
| $10$ | $16$ |
| $11$ | $16$ |
| $12$ | $16$ |
| $13$ | $16$ |
| $14$ | $16$ |
| $15$ | $16$ |

**Can anyone help me in finding correct formula?**

As a try, I prepared this **Formula**

$$\LARGE\boxed{2^{\lfloor\log_2(x)\rfloor}}$$

where $x$ is the input.

In **Code**

```
Math.pow(2, Math.floor(Math.log2(K))
```

Comment: @Useless check the edit

Comment: Is the output for $2$ and $3$ is $4 \cdot 2^3$ or $4 \cdot 2^2$?

Comment: @JaideepKhare return 2 when the input is 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this function $$f(0)=1 \quad;\;f(n)= 2^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor+1} \; \text{if} ~ n \ge 1$$

Comment: That's it thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for computer code only dealing with integers, here is a bit of `c++` based on bit operations:

```
// For simplicity, assume that the input 'n' is of type unsigned int.

unsigned int m = 1;
while (m <= n) m <<= 1; // could be written as m *= 2

return m;
```

Using this, you do not have to deal with floating point arithmetic and rounding errors. The while loop will run only $O(\log n)$ times.

If you do not want to use additional variables, then use this:

```
while (n != (n | (n >> 1))) n |= (n >> 1);
return (n + 1);
```